# Como enviar mais de um valor em um elemento select do form html?

Tags: html, formulário

Estou criando um formulário e para alguns campos eu preciso enviar mais de um valor e não sei se a forma que estou fazendo é a melhor ou não.

```
<select name="itens[]">
   <option value=""></option>
   <option value="1||Primeiro Item">Primeiro Item</option>
   <option value="2||Segundo Item">Segundo Item</option>
   <option value="3||Terceiro Item">Terceiro Item</option>
</select>
```

Então, tenho esse elemento que no value estou passando tanto o `ID` quanto o `NOME` do campo e estou separando por dois pipes (||) , e estou fazendo isso pois preciso guardar tanto o id quanto o nome que estava no momento quando salvar.

Minha dúvida é a seguinta, essa forma funciona? Sim, pois no outro lado, posso dar um explode, por exemplo e com isso separar os valores, mas é a forma correta ou não tem uma forma correta, mas sim uma melhor?!

Comment: Para que queres passar o NOME? O ID não te bastava?

Comment: Já testaste assim? Se calhar era boa ideia testares o que tentas fazer

Comment: O nome eu preciso para saber qual era no momento, e isso é o que mais importa, pois se for um valor e esse valor alterar num futuro, não afeta o dado salvo no passado, e guardando o id eu ainda tenho uma comparabilidade do que era e do que é no momento.

Comment: @JorgeB. já testei sim e funciona, mas não sei se tem alguma outra forma mais correta para se fazer isso!

Comment: Eu prefiro passar só os `ID`, porque os meus `NOME` costumam estar numa tabela na base de dados.

Exemplo `tabela_itens` com `ID` e `NOME`

Comment: Eu também tenho o costume de fazer dessa forma, e acho que a maioria é assim, mas esse é um caso digamos especial.

Comment: @MarceloDiniz com esse tratamento da resposta mais valia ter uma tabela, OU criar constantes para fazer isso (no caso de ser PHP criar `define()`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O que você fez não está errado. É muito comum separar os valores por `,` também. Mas acredito que o jeito mais apropriado é passar um `JSON`. Você pode passar utilizando a notação vetorial como

```
<select name="itens[]">
   <option value=""></option>
   <option value="[1,Primeiro Item]">Primeiro Item</option>
   <option value="[2,Segundo Item]">Segundo Item</option>
   <option value="[3,Terceiro Item]">Terceiro Item</option>
</select>
```

ou a de um objeto como

```
<select name="itens[]">
   <option value=""></option>
   <option value="{'id' : 1, 'desc': 'Primeiro Item'}">Primeiro Item</option>
   <option value="{'id' : 2, 'desc': 'Segundo Item'}">Segundo Item</option>
   <option value="{'id' : 3, 'desc': 'Terceito Item'}">Tericeiro Item</option>
</select>
```

A segunda opção descreve melhor seus dados, além de você poder utilizar o `JSON.stringify()` para a converter seus objetos em string.

Comment: Boa Bruno, é algo que pensei também, mas me fala uma coisa, de qualquer forma não deixa de ser uma string, sendo que do lado do servidor eu tenho que dar um `json_decode` ou algo do gênero  correto?

Comment: sim ainda é preciso esse tratamento